# Reopening jQuery menu after page loaded

Tags: html, jquery, jquery-events

I have a vertical 2 level jQuery menu, and I'd need that after a link has been clicked and the new page loaded, the menu stay open with the selected link highlighted.
Here is my menu code:

```
<div id="my-menu">
    <ul>
        <li><span class="toggle">Una Passione</span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="Trefratelli.aspx">Tre Fratelli</a></li>
                <li><a href="Conlenostremani.aspx">Con le nostre mani</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">La nostra storia</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Il video</a></li>
                <li><a href="Libro.aspx">Il libro</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><span class="toggle">Icone</span>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="Icone_Brera.aspx">Brera</a></li>
                <li><a href="Icone_Magenta.aspx">Magenta</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

and here the jQuery code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $("span.toggle").next().hide();
    $("span.toggleinterno").next().hide();

    $("#my-menu a, #my-menu span.toggle").click(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate( {
            color:"red"
        }, 300);
    });

    $("span.toggle").click(function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('second')) {
            $(this).removeClass('second');
        } else {
            $(this).addClass('second');
        }
    });  

    $("#my-menu a, #my-menu span.toggleinterno").click(function() {
        $(this).stop().animate( {
            fontSize:"17px",
            //paddingLeft:"10px",
            color:"black"
        }, 300);
    }, function() {
        $(this).stop().animate( {
            //fontSize:"14px",
            paddingLeft:"15",
            color:"#808080"
        }, 300);
    });

    $("span.toggle").css("cursor", "pointer");
    $("span.toggleinterno").css("cursor", "pointer");

    $("span.toggle").click(function() {
        $(this).next().toggle(1000);
    });

    $("span.toggleinterno").click(function() {
        $("span.toggleinterno").css("width", "100px");
        $(this).next().toggle(1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: What have you tried? From the code examples you've provided, there's no indication of what you've attempted so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
var url = window.location.pathname.match(/.*\/(.*)$/)[1];
var $activelink =  $('#my-menu a[href="' + url + '"]');
var $openmenu = $('#my-menu ul ul').has(activelink);

$activelink.addClass('hilight');
$openmenu.show();
```